# Regex: Don't match string which is already part of a word

Tags: python, regex

This sounds like it shuold be something simple, so I think I might be missing something.

Say I want to use a regular expression to match the string "cat", I can do this fine, however, I don't want to match "concatenate" for example, or any other word that contains "cat", I just want "cat" on its own.

How would I achieve this? I considered something like the following:

`(CAT|Cat|cat|)( )*`

But this doesn't seem to work correctly. I can't add a space on either side in case "Cat" is the first word in the sentence/line.

Is there a way to exclude characters using regular expressions? Something like "Not A-z or 0-9 either side of "cat" "?

Comment: What is your regex flavour? What language/tool do you use?

Comment: This will be used within a Python program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use word boundary:

```
\bcat\b
```

If you want to disallow certain characters only then use lookarounds:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])cat(?![a-zA-Z0-9])
```

Comment: Word boundaries is what I was looking for, many thanks! I will accept this answer when Stack Overflow lets me.

Answer (score 3):

Try word boundaries:

```
/\bcat\b/gi
```

[***Demo***](https://regex101.com/r/mI1dD8/1)

---

A [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), `\b`, is a [zero-length assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html) that essentially looks for a word character followed by a non-word character or visa versa (`\w\W|\W\w|^\w|\w$`).